# How to install JBoss to match with entry in classpath-File

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have to build an old J2EE-Application. The Application uses JBoss 4.0.
When I open the source in Eclipse, I get the Error

The import javax.ejb cannot be resolved.

The .classpath-File contains the following content:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="ejbModule"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/jsf"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.runtimeTarget/JBoss v4.0"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
```

I think my problem is because it will not find `org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.runtimeTarget/JBoss v4.0`. How can I fix this? What do I have to install and configure, that my project will find the libraries?

Comment: So you have a JBoss 4.0 server defined in eclipse? If you don't I can try and provide an answer that helps you create it but with your reputation I'm pretty sure you know how ;-)  If thats not the case and you just need to change the projects runtime let me know and I can help with that as well, unfortunately I have to do it quite frequently O_o

Comment: @JGlass Unfortunately, I am a C # developer and know less well with Eclipse. It would be great if you could support me.

Comment: Did you get things figured out?  If not, under the "Servers" tab, what server is listed?